# Stm32H747 DCMI DMA overflow interrupt

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, dma

I was trying to replicate the stm32h747 Disco DCMI_Snapshot example. The code goes into overflow interrupt management.

Debug findings:
During debug the value of isr_value was found to be 25 but when running my code the value is 26.

```
uint32_t isr_value = READ_REG(hdcmi->Instance->MISR);
/* Overflow interrupt management ********************************************/
  if ((isr_value & DCMI_FLAG_OVRRI) == DCMI_FLAG_OVRRI)
  {
    /* Clear the Overflow flag */
    __HAL_DCMI_CLEAR_FLAG(hdcmi, DCMI_FLAG_OVRRI);

    /* Update error code */
    hdcmi->ErrorCode |= HAL_DCMI_ERROR_OVR;

    /* Change DCMI state */
    hdcmi->State = HAL_DCMI_STATE_ERROR;

    /* Set the overflow callback */
    hdcmi->DMA_Handle->XferAbortCallback = DCMI_DMAError;

    /* Abort the DMA Transfer */
    (void)HAL_DMA_Abort_IT(hdcmi->DMA_Handle);
  }
```

Tried toggling the interrupts in the ioc file, enabled all the interrupts and changed byte width(default set to byte).

Comment: I am having same issue, I had tried configuring different DMA with highest priority but it didn't help. [Ref Manual page 1227](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0399-stm32h745755-and-stm32h747757-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) says that this interrupt occurs when new data arrives before previous data was transferred, did you check your clock configs?